# Access github package from github actions services section

Tags: docker, github-actions, github-token

With GitHub Actions I'm trying to set up a service that runs a specific image (MySQL preloaded with a database) that I have pushed to ghcr.io however when it runs I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: denied
Warning: Docker pull failed with exit code 1, back off 8.976 seconds before retry.
```

Workflow:

```yaml
services:
  mysql:
    image: ghcr.io/my-name/my-image
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

I see it does the following:

```
/usr/bin/docker --config /home/runner/work/_temp/.docker_[...] login ghcr.io -u myusername --password-stdin
```

There is no feedback so not sure if it is logged in or not. And, then:

```
/usr/bin/docker --config /home/runner/work/_temp/.docker[...] pull ghcr.io/my-name/my-image
```

And then I get that error.

I have found many examples (see below) to use `GITHUB_TOKEN` but not how to use it within the `services` section so I am not sure if this works or what the syntax would be. So is it even possible to use with `services` or not? Also have given the repository in which the GitHub action is defined access to the specific package.

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Log in to the Container registry
    uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
    with:
      registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
      username: ${{ github.actor }}
      password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Is that image public?

Comment: No it is a private image

Comment: Then, to "**Download an existing container**", "**If the container is private, only workflows running in repositories that are given read permission on that container can download the container.**". Ref: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/managing-github-packages-using-github-actions-workflows/publishing-and-installing-a-package-with-github-actions#default-permissions-and-access-settings-for-containers-modified-through-workflows

Comment: You need to configure the image's read visibility for this particular workflow. See https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/configuring-a-packages-access-control-and-visibility.

Comment: Yes thank you I was aware of that so had given access but did not help. I actually thought that would have been enough so not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Right. Maybe, you need to revisit and verify all the steps one by one. BTW, have you tried using a [PAT](https://github.com/docker/login-action#github-container-registry)?

Comment: So I added the repository which contains the action in the package settings under:
Manage Actions access
Pick the repositories that can access this package using GitHub Actions.

And I set the "Inherit access from source repository (recommended) "

Regarding the PAT, I have setup some access tokens but I do not understand what the syntax under services would be but also how it would know which token to use.

Comment: You can [create a PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) with more granular privileges and try that in place of `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

Comment: Yes thanks but is it possible to use it with the services sections because I cannot find any examples for that. So I do not understand what the syntax would be to use it there.,

Comment: See this official example https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-of-jobsjob_idservicesservice_idcredentials.

Comment: Also, see [`jobs.<job_id>.services.<service_id>.credentials`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservicesservice_idcredentials).

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found the issue, in my workflow (started from default template) I had:

```
permissions:
  contents: read
```

Then I saw this:

> Setting permissions in the workflow
>
> A new permissions key supported at the workflow and job level enables
> you to specify which permissions you want for the token. **Any
> permission that is absent from the list will be set to none.**

This caused *packages* to be set to **none**. Removing the whole permissions or adding:

```
packages: read
```

fixes this issue I had, thanks for the help.

Comment: From your earlier comments, I gathered that all the permissions' issues were already taken care of and the workflow in the question itself also had this missing. Anyway, glad you figured this out. Cheers!

Comment: Yes it would have helped if I had shown my whole config then you would probably have noticed. Thank for your help though it did help me to see the login was not the issue :)

Comment: Yes, it would have. You're welcome! :)